# How to do sum of a column in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have :

name   | no
a          10
b         20
c         30

I want to sum no., that means I want x=60
how can I do that in PIG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have your dataset in 'data' variable, here is the code:

```
DESCRIBE data
data: (name, no)

data_grp = GROUP data ALL;
result = FOREACH data_grp GENERATE SUM(data.no);
```